# Query failed-too long

Tags: mysql

```html
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chapter LEFT JOIN page ON chapter.chapterID=page.chapterID WHERE page.category AND chapter.category LIKE 'Novice' GROUP BY page.pageID,page.chapterID  ")or die('Query failed');
```

I have the following query but i also want to add the following `WHERE chapter.lectureID=1` how can i do so. i tried this :

```html
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chapter LEFT JOIN page ON chapter.chapterID=page.chapterID WHERE chapter.lectureID=1,page.category AND chapter.category LIKE 'Novice' GROUP BY page.pageID,page.chapterID  ")or die('Query failed');
```

But query failed.

Comment: You should try to output the `mysql_error()`, which should tell you something like "You have an error in your syntax near `chapter.lectureID=1,page.category AND chapter.category`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `,page.category` from the `WHERE` clause. It has no reason to be there because it is not being compared to a value.

```
$query = mysql_query("
  SELECT * FROM chapter 
  LEFT JOIN page ON chapter.chapterID=page.chapterID 
  WHERE chapter.lectureID = 1 
    AND chapter.category LIKE 'Novice' 
  GROUP BY page.pageID,page.chapterID
")or die('Query failed');
```

Also, you are using a `LIKE` operator and you are passing it a string, not a pattern. You could change `'Novice'` to `'%Novice%'`, which will match anything containing that string.

Comment: i agree, the `page.category` was for nothing there.